TTGO T-Call ESP32 SIM800L solar charging problem
I'm sending sensor data via GPRS to cloud like described here but with some alterations:
https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-sim800l-publish-data-to-cloud/
My issue is charging the battery via a solar panel.
Battery is connected directly to the board via JST connector and the solar panel to 5V on board as instructed in some other tutorials. Shouldn't be a problem since the highest voltage from the panel I measured is about 5.1V.
Also, I figured that the GSM modem needs about 300mA current in order to be able to acquire GPRS signal and send data.
Everything is fine when the panel is properly lit (high enough current comes in) or when there is no sun at all - powering from the battery. Both cases are giving >300mA current which is enough for the program to run.
What doesn't work is when the IP5306 detects a "charging" voltage as in "USB connected" but the current is not sufficient to run the modem (shade). In this case it would all be fine if the IP5306 would let the current come directly from the battery. But it's not the case since it's hot switching to input power.
I couldn't find an option in the IP5306 registers to disable this hot switching and always use battery power.
Question:
How do I ensure that there is always enough current to the ESP32 board from outside? I'm thinking of using an external solar/charger/battery unit which I could connect directly to the battery node on ESP32 board and not use the IP5306 at all. Can someone think of a circuit out of the box like this?
HW used:
Batteries tried:

EEMB Lithium Polymer Battery 3.7V 2000mAh 103454 Rechargeable Lipo Battery with JST Connector

Li-ion 18650 3.7V (different capacities, different manufacturers)


Solar panels tried:

5 W Solar Module for DC 5 V Outdoor

28W Portable Solar Charger 2-Port USB(5V/4A total), IPX4, Solar Panel with Digital Ammeter and Zipper for Protection (better coverage of the "insufficiency window" but the issue still persists)



You can use a power path controller, like the Texas Instruments BQ25703A.
